# AWS structure of S3 trigger

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am building a Python Lambda in AWS and wanted to add an S3 trigger to it. Following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) I saw how to get the bucket and key on which I got the trigger using:

```py
def func(event):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
```

There is an example of such an object in the link, but I wasn't able, however, to find a description of the entire event object anywhere in AWS' documentation.

Is there a documentation for this object's structure? Where might I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find documentation about the whole object in the S3 documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html

I would also advise to iterate the records, because there could be multiple at once:

```py
for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']

    [...]
```